# Initialize the textfields in Sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch form, which has two textfields. I want to assign some text to them on page load. I tried setting values in init and launch functions. But in those function textfield  are not available, they are undefined. So which event should be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Either set the values with the `setRecord({textFieldName1: "value", textFieldName2: "value"})` method of the container, or assign an id to the text fields and access them via `Ext.getCmp('textFieldName').setValue("value")` in the `initialize`method of the container.

Comment: Thanks for replying dp1000. The problem is Ext.getCmp('texFieldName') is undefined in initialize function and I think I can't use setRecords too.

Comment: Code:  <code> config: {                                                                       //Referances to textfiled
        refs: {
            user: '#login>#fields>#txtUserName',
            password: '#login>#fields>#passwordField'
        }
    },
     //Init function
    init: function () {   
            this.getUser()._value = localStorage.getItem("UserID");
            this.getPassword()._value = localStorage.getItem("Password");
    }, <code>                                                                   This code is written in controller file.

Comment: proper formatting of your code would be nice next time. For your `refs`you just can use `user: '#txtUserName'`and then instead of setting the fields private value `_value` you should try to use the `setValue`method. So in your init mehtod write `this.getUser.setValue(localStorage.getItem("UserID"))` instead.

Comment: Sorry for that dp1000, yes I will use  setValue function. I found  out my problem, I was trying to set value in init function, but textfield were not yet created there. Now I found the function where to initialize these fields. But the problem I am facing now is, assigned values are not reflected. In developer tool textfiled values were changed, but not visible on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `value` property directly ? Setting the value will make the `textfield` fill with the corresponding value of `value` property i.e in our case, "`Sample Text 1`" etc ..

e.g

```
   { 
     xtype:'textfield,  
     value:'Sample Text 1 ',
   },
   { 
     xtype:'textfield,  
     value:'Sample Text 2 ',
   }
```

Comment: No I cant use value property, because I need to assign values conditionally.

Comment: You want to set the values conditionally, also, you don't want to set it predefined? Huh ... What are you trying to do?

Comment: My actual need is to implement remember me functionality. So when remember me is checked I ll save the value and set at login page is loaded.